# How to write back changed CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Before flagging as duplicate, I have read 5 other topics similar to this but did not seem to work.

I have been able to change a value in a CSV file. However, I can not figure out how to write back the whole file. I have only been able to write back the changed line.

Code:

```
import csv

            file=open("stock.csv")
            stockfile= csv.reader(file)
            for line in stockfile:
                if GTIN in line:
                    currentstock= line[2]
                    targetstock = line[3]
                    newstock = (int(currentstock) - int(Quantity))
                    targetstock = str(targetstock)
                    newstock = str(newstock)
                    line[2]= int(newstock)
                    print(line)
                    with open("output.csv","w") as outfile:
                        newdata = csv.writer(outfile)
                        newdata.writerow(line)
                        if newstock<targetstock:
                            print("stock needs updating...please wait a moment")
                        else:
                            print("stock is fine")
```

Stock.csv :

```
86947367,banana,100,40
78364721,apple,50,20
35619833,orange,20,30
84716491,sweets,200,90
46389121,chicken,40,10
```

output.CSV: ( only writes back the changed line and not the rest of the file)

```
86947367    banana  1   40
```

I want:

```
    86947367,banana,1,40
    78364721,apple,50,20
    35619833,orange,20,30
    84716491,sweets,200,90
    46389121,chicken,40,10
```

thank you.

Comment: I noticed that you are reading stockfile line by line.

I also noticed that the only time anything is written to output.csv if the following condition is met:
`if GTIN in line:`

Take a close look at what is enclosed in that if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite the output file again and again here:

```
with open("output.csv","w") as outfile:
```

Move this line to the top:

```
with open("output.csv","w") as outfile, open("stock.csv") as infile:
    stockfile= csv.reader(infile)
    newdata = csv.writer(outfile)
        for line in stockfile:
             # ...
             newdata.writerow(line)
             # ....
```

Full working example:

```
import csv

GTIN = 'banana'
Quantity = 99

with open("output.csv","w") as outfile, open("stock.csv") as infile:
    stockfile= csv.reader(infile)
    newdata = csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in stockfile:
        if GTIN in line:
            currentstock= line[2]
            targetstock = line[3]
            newstock = (int(currentstock) - int(Quantity))
            targetstock = str(targetstock)
            newstock = str(newstock)
            line[2]= int(newstock)
            print(line)
            if newstock<targetstock:
                print("stock needs updating...please wait a moment")
            else:
                print("stock is fine")
        newdata.writerow(line)
```

Output:

```
86947367,banana,1,40
78364721,apple,50,20
35619833,orange,20,30
84716491,sweets,200,90
46389121,chicken,40,10
```

Comment: thank you so much :) I forgot to outdent the write row line . thankss, all makes sense.